# Accurate translation of list of allergens

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, alimentation, santé-et-médecine

I need to be able to say precisely in French the following.

> I am allergic to all nuts, legumes and pulses. This includes for
>   example peanuts, peas, chickpeas and beans.

My problem is that I am not sure these words translate literally and correctly from English. How would you say it in French?

Google translate gives.

> Je suis allergique à toutes les noix, les légumineuses et les légumes
>   secs. Cela comprend par exemple les arachides, les pois, les pois
>   chiches et les haricots.

Does "noix" include cashew nuts, brazil nuts etc.? Does "haricots" include black beans, baked beans, runner beans and so on?   Does "légumes secs" include chickpeas? Does "légumineuse" include peas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Fruits à coque* is the French term that will include all types of nuts, i.e. walnuts (*noix*), peanuts (*arachides*), cashew nuts (*noix de cajou*), etc...

*Légumes secs* include all pulses. List on [Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9gumes_secs), you'll only have to click to have their names in English. *Légumes secs* include chickpeas (*poids chiches*), all types of [dry beans](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haricot#Types_de_haricots_secs_et_demi-secs_par_la_couleur). Baked beans are just a variety of *haricots secs*, you would not normally have "baked beans" in France but beware of [Cassoulet](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassoulet).

*Légumineuses* is a more generic term that I think include some of the preceding and some roots, like soybean (*soja*) and lupins, I expect [wikipedia list](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabaceae) might help.

You should be aware that labeling is not as strict in France as it is in Britain (I would not know about other countries) but if you are planning a trip to France you can have a look at this [governmental website](http://www.economie.gouv.fr/dgccrf/Publications/Vie-pratique/Fiches-pratiques/Allergene-alimentaire) although it is in French they have a leaflet you can download [in French](http://www.economie.gouv.fr/files/directions_services/dgccrf/documentation/publications/depliants/allergenes_fr.pdf) and [in English](http://www.economie.gouv.fr/files/directions_services/dgccrf/documentation/publications/depliants/allergens_anglais.pdf) and by comparing the two you might come up with something useful.

(I hesitated posting this answer here since it is not really about French language, at least I've out stepped the scope of French language and I'll be very happy to delete my answer once it's served its purpose of trying to help.)

Comment: "Fruits à coque" +1

Answer (score 2):

I don't usually post, but part of this answer seems misleading, as *fruits a coque* appears to refer to tree nuts, not peanuts, as peanuts are not nuts.

see for example:
https://allergies.ooreka.fr/comprendre/allergie-fruits-a-coque
https://www.labellord.eu/fr/blog/la-difference-entre-les-noix-et-les-arachides.html